# asp.net core error: ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'sslmode'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently trying out Asp.net core with MySQL and I am also new to Asp.net core MVC. The first time I tried to fetch data I got the following error

```
MySqlException: The host localhost does not support SSL connections.
```

After researched i found out that i needed to add **SslMode=none** at the connection string so i added it like this 
`"server=127.0.0.1;database=test;uid=root;password=;SslMode=none;"`

it solved the error but now when I try to register a user with the default user authentication module of asp.net core, I get the following stack trace error

```
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary<string, string> parsetable, string connectionString, bool buildChain, Dictionary<string, string> synonyms)
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(string connectionString, Dictionary<string, string> synonyms)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(string connectionString)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(string connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, ref DbConnectionOptions userConnectionOptions)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(string value)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef.get_Value()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection+<OpenAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable+AsyncEnumerator+<BufferlessMoveNext>d__9.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy+<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable+AsyncEnumerator+<MoveNext>d__8.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+SelectAsyncEnumerable+SelectAsyncEnumerator+<MoveNext>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+<_FirstOrDefault>d__82.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable+Enumerator+<MoveNext>d__3.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+SelectAsyncEnumerable+SelectAsyncEnumerator+<MoveNext>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+ExceptionInterceptor+EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor+<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserValidator+<ValidateUserName>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserValidator+<ValidateAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager+<ValidateUserInternal>d__157.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager+<CreateAsync>d__68.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager+<CreateAsync>d__73.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
FirstASP.NETCore.Controllers.AccountController+<Register>d__10.MoveNext() in AccountController.cs
+
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware+<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya  ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'sslmode'.
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary<string, string> parsetable, string connectionString, bool buildChain, Dictionary<string, string> synonyms)

Comment: Your EntityFramework seems to try to talk with a Microsoft SQL Server database, not a MySQL database. Have you setup Entity Framework to use MySQL as described  [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html)?

Comment: @NineBerry i think the problems could be here:  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));  if so could you provide a sample on how i can connect to mysql

Comment: That is exactly your problem `UseSqlServer()` means MS Sql Server. MySQL is `UseMySQL()`

Answer (score 4):

1) Go to package manager console

[image]

2) Install package: MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

[image]

3) Now fetch connection string in the Startup.cs like shown below.

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options 
               =>options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```