# The package may not be fully compatible .Net core 2.1 with MySql.Data.Entity (6.10.7)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Hi everyone I connect Web API Asp.Net Core2.1 with MySql but I have a problem, do not get data.
When I Instal MySql.Data.Entity (6.10.7). Have a warning like a picture below:
I read a  post "[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797892/net-core-2-0-package-was-restored-using-netframework-4-6-1-instead-of-target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797892/net-core-2-0-package-was-restored-using-netframework-4-6-1-instead-of-target)" but do not fix that problem. Help me Please!

[image]

Comment: Use MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore and for its use in Startup.cs, Check my answer for https://stackoverflow.com/a/51708989/6417765.

Comment: Thanks. Have other error likes "https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2914". I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

The package `MySQL.Data.Entity` does not support ASP.NET core which you are using - it [only shows .NET Framework 4.6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/) under "Dependencies".

Try using the [`MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore) instead.

Comment: Thank you.  However, appearing other error when I get data 

"An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommandBuilderFactory..ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.IDiagnosticsLogger`1<Command>, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalTypeMapper)'.
MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLCommandBuilderFactory..ctor(IDiagnosticsLogger<Command> logger, IRelationalTypeMapper typeMapper)"

Comment: What NuGET packages are listed in your project now?

Comment: Include
microsoft.aspnetcore.webapi.client
microsoft.aspnetcore.webapi.app
MySql.Data
MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore
MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

Comment: Error likes "https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2914". I don't know why?